# ExecutionException: com.google.android.apps.gsa.sidekick.main.h.n: Could not complete scheduled request to refresh entries. ClientErrorCode: 3

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack

logcat:

```
2019-03-14 06:55:50.281 3007-9609/? E/EntrySyncManager: Cannot determine account name: drop request
2019-03-14 06:55:50.287 3007-9609/? E/NowController: Failed to access data from EntryProvider. ExecutionException.
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.android.apps.gsa.sidekick.main.h.n: Could not complete scheduled request to refresh entries. ClientErrorCode: 3
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.eA(SourceFile:85)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.get(SourceFile:23)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.l.get(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.be.cbB(SourceFile:49)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.be.cbA(SourceFile:181)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.bh.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.at.run(SourceFile:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.g.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.i.run(SourceFile:6)
     Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.sidekick.main.h.n: Could not complete scheduled request to refresh entries. ClientErrorCode: 3
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.ar.az(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.q.ap(SourceFile:7)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.p.run(SourceFile:32)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.bt.execute(SourceFile:3)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.b(SourceFile:275)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.addListener(SourceFile:135)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.p.b(SourceFile:3)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.h.a(SourceFile:16)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.h.a(SourceFile:13)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.be.cbB(SourceFile:47)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.be.cbA(SourceFile:181) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.bh.run(Unknown Source:2) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.at.run(SourceFile:4) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.g.run(Unknown Source:4) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.i.run(SourceFile:6)
```

I am using jetpack navigation, from fragmentOne I open fragmentTwo, then when I press back button this error occurs. I have looked upper in the logcat but no other error, just this one. My navigation graph:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@id/home_fragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/home_fragment"
        android:name="com.myapp.ui.fragments.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="m"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_home_fragment_to_other_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/other_fragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/other_fragment"
        android:name="com.myapp.ui.fragments.other.OtherFragment"
        android:label="n"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_other" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_other_fragment_to_home_fragment2"
            app:destination="@id/home_fragment" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

And this is how I open the fragmentTwo, v is a view from OnClickListener:

```
v.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_home_fragment_to_other_fragment)
```

I have no clue on what it can be, very annoying. If you need more details, please ask

Comment: Is this on debug or on release?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but the real problem is mostly a few lines above this error on the LogCat.
In my case i was setting on click listener to a floating button after inflating the layout and once  I was setting the text of a button on my holder as an int and that caused the problem, cause I need to use a classic String.valueOf() which fixed my problem.

So check if you are doing something like that but as i said check the logcat first.